# What is the best way to retain ViewModel values from GET ActionResult to the Post ActionResult?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Given that you have an ActionResult Form and a Post ActionResult Form and you have a value that does not need to appear in the view.

```
    public ActionResult Form()
    {
        FormModel formModel = new FormModel();
        formModel.UploadRecordID = 99;
        return View(formModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Form(FormModel formModel)
    {
        long recordID = formModel.UploadRecordID;
    }
```

What is the best way to retain that value?

One way is that you can create a hidden field in your view.

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UploadRecordID);
```

Is that the best way to do this? Are there any other ways you could do it, if so what are the advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: Best is rather subjective. Another option is to store it in the session. This has an advantage over the hidden method in that users cannot manipulate the hidden input. On the other hand, you could run into other problems and I personally wouldn't recommend using the session in this case. A cleaner option would be to save the ID to a database in the Get, and read it back in the Post, if that's an option. However, if you are going to generate the UploadRecordID in the Get, and don't use the value in the View, why don't you just generate it in the Post without passing it back and forth?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, agreed trying to avoid Session. As for the UploadRecordID, to clarify it is being passed in from the url so that it can be used to get a record and pre-populate some values. But then in the Post we then need to do other post-process actions on that record after posting.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use TempData like:

```
TempData["formModel"] = formModel;
```

and in post action:

```
FormModel formModel = TempData["formModel"];
```